# How can I fix node-sass usage is deprecated?

Tags: node.js, angular, sass

Node-sass does not work. I see a message that node-sass is deprecated and will be removed in a future major version. I already uninstalled many times with no effect. I could still uninstall again. How could I solve?

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the obvious "if this isn't your own code, but some framework's start project: use their latest version", if that is not the case you can use the [npm-ls](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-ls) command to generate the full dependency tree for your project.

1. Use `npm ls --all > dependencylist.txt` to write that tree to a text file you can just open in your editor, then
2. find any mention of node-sass in `dependencylist.txt`, and
3. look up in the tree to find out which of your *direct* dependencies has a deeply nested indirect dependency on node-sass. Then
4. update those dependencies to their latest versions,
5. delete your `node_modules` dir, and finally
6. rerun `npm install`.

And of course, remember to never install anything globally, so if you made the mistake of installing `node-sass` using the `-g` flag, you'll have to also remember to uninstall it globally with that same `-g` flag.